# NuGet package restore failure

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

After code migration in bit bucket facing issue to build the solution in visual studio .

> Error:
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error     The command ""C:...nuget\nuget.exe" restore C:\Users..\packages.config -RequireConsent -solutionDir C:\Users.." exited with code 1.
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     restore: invalid arguments. M5Mantle.Tests

Tried :
cleaning nuget cache ,
update solution package ,
allowed automatic download of nuget package .

any alternative approach I can look into to resolve the issue .

Comment: Could you please share your full restore command with us?

Comment: As for me, I used `<Exec Command="C:\xxx\nuget.exe restore C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\xxx\ConsoleApp197\packages.config -RequireConsent -solutionDir C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp197"></Exec>`. And I think your restore command used some msbuild properties which missed their own values, so please share it with us and your `csproj` file.

Comment: any update about this issue, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

> Error The command ""C:...nuget\nuget.exe" restore
> C:\Users..\packages.config -RequireConsent -solutionDir C:\Users.."
> exited with code 1.

The issue is quite obvious. The command which shows on the error is already parsed by VS IDE.

```
"C:...nuget\nuget.exe" restore C:\Users..\packages.config -RequireConsent -solutionDir C:\Users..
```

And that is the full, direct command. And you can type it in CMD command to test whether it is right.

You could find that:

`C:...nuget\nuget.exe` is not a right, legal full path which it can find the right nuget.exe.

`C:\Users..\packages.config` is not right. And it cannot find the `packages.config` of the specific project folder.

`C:\Users..` is not a right solution folder.

**So** not sure whether your restore command has used some msbuild properties like `$(xxx)` which are missing or some sys environment variables.

So you should check your restore command very carefully and if necessary, please share it with us and csproj file so that we can find the problem in the right direction.

**As for me**, I used this:

```
<Target Name="test123" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec Command="C:\xxx\nuget.exe restore $(ProjectDir)packages.config -RequireConsent -solutionDir $(SolutionDir)"></Exec>
</Target>
```